# Skipping inner methods in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, atg

I am trying to test the below method using mockito. I wanted to skip `getProfileItemFinder().retrieveEmailRecipient(email)` method call when executing `class.getUserWishList("abc@gmail.com")`;

I have tried the below code, but whenever I am trying to run the code I am getting mockito exception at doReturn. Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

**Sample Mock Method:**

```
profileItemFinder = spy(new TestProfileItemFinder());
doReturn(profileItem).when( profileItemFinder.retrieveEmailRecipient(email));
```

**Original Method:**

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getUserWishList(String email) {
    // JSONArray profileGiftList = new JSONArray();
    ---------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------
    if (email != null) {

        RepositoryItem profileItem = getProfileItemFinder().retrieveEmailRecipient(email);

        if (profileItem != null) {
      ----------------------------------
      --------------------------------

    }

            }
        }
    }

    ---------------------------

}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: I got the issue profileItem is a  atg repository item and it was not initializing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that email and profileItem are rightly defined above, now instead of:

```
doReturn(profileItem).when( profileItemFinder.retrieveEmailRecipient(email));
```

Try below and check once,

```
doReturn(profileItem).when( getProfileItemFinder().retrieveEmailRecipient(email));
```

Comment: got the issue profileItem is a atg repository item and it was not initializing properly. Thanks for the answer.